# Bcrypt NodeJS compare password always returning false

Tags: node.js, webcrypto-api, nodejs-server, jbcrypt

So obviously i am using bcrypt to register and hash my password and that works.
And now i am making an login where i have to compare the form password and the hashed password in the database and this is how i do this:

```
// Get post data
let email = req.body.email;
let password = req.body.password;

con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", email, function (err, result, fields) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, function(err, result) {
        if (err) { throw (err); }
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

it always returns false; if i console.log result[0].password, i get my hashed password back so thats good but why does it always return false?

Comment: is it `bcryptjs` or `bcrypt`

Comment: Also, make sure there should not be 2 entries for same email.

Comment: also make sure that both the original password that was crypted and the one just entered don't have weird trailing newlines or other whitespace; probably useful to trim the input assuming whitespace is not valid at either end of  your passwords.

Comment: i am using bcryptjs because i couldn't use bcrypt for some weird reason

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try changing your if statement to:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", email, function (err,
     result, fields) {
         bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, function(err, result) {
             if (!result) { throw (err); }
             console.log(result);
         }); 
    });
```

Comment: The error i get is 'null'. I do not understand why this is.

Comment: The documentation of bcryptjs states that at the end you will get a result which is either false or true, depending on the password and hash you are trying to compare: [link](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js)